# RunAction: WithKey: Not working in sprite kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am using following code to fire a missile.

```
SKAction *missileMoveAction = [SKAction moveTo:destination duration:1.0];

SKAction *moveMissileActionWithDone = [SKAction sequence:@[_missileShootSound, missileMoveAction]];

[_cannonMissile runAction:moveMissileActionWithDone];
```

This is working fine but as soon as i use

```
[_cannonMissile runAction:moveMissileActionWithDone withKey:@"Canon_Fired"];
```

Nothing happen the run action do not move the object to destination. What is the problem with using **RunAction: WithKey:**?

Comment: You might want to group the actions for sound as well as missile move. Also, have you added the missile to the scene before running an action on it? Please include additional code...

Comment: Yes it has been added. As i mentioned it is working fine as soon as i use without key [_cannonMissile runAction:moveMissileActionWithDone];

Comment: Is it possible that there is another action with the same key being run immediately afterwards? This would remove the original action and perform the new one. Maybe if the code above is called in a method that is called multiple times in quick succession while "destination" has changed?

Comment: I am calling this method in update so maybe keys are repeated.

Comment: Ah that explains it. Update is called after every frame is rendered. That means that when there is no key, the sprite is asked to do a new action, the action is added to the list of actions to perform. When you have a key however, there is already an action in the list with the same key, the previous action is cancelled/removed. Unless you have a very specific reason I don't think you should be calling it from update. If you must then you can keep a BOOL that says action has started, and add a block to the action that resets the BOOL once the action is completed.